# how do I integrate, a function with many arguments using matlab

Tags: matlab, int

If I'm to integrate a function

y = -((F+h)*M^3*(cosh(h*M)+M*beta*sinh(h*M)))/(h*M*cosh(h*M)+(-1+h*M^2*beta)*sinh(h*M))- (alpha*(M^2*(F+h)*(-1+2*h^2*M^2+ cosh(2*h*M)-2*h*M*sinh(2*h*M)))/(8*(h*M*cosh(h*M)+(-1+h*M^2*beta)*sinh(h*M))^2));

with respect to x, where

```
phi = 0.6;
x = 0.5;
M = 2;
theta = -1:0.5:1.5;
F = theta - 1;
h = 1 + phi*cos(2*pi*x);
alpha = 0.2;beta = 0.0;
```

I have written an Mfile

```
function r = parameterIntegrate(F,h,M,beta,alpha,theta,phi)
% defining a nested function that uses one variable
phi = 0.6;
x = 0.5;
r = quad(@testf,0,1 + phi*cos(2*pi*x));
% simpson's rule from 0 to h
function y = testf(x)
h = 1 + phi*cos(2*pi*x);
theta = -1:0.5:1.5;
F = theta - 1;
M = 2;
beta = 0;
alpha = 0;
y = -((F+h)*M^3*(cosh(h*M)+M*beta*sinh(h*M)))/(h*M*cosh(h*M)+(-1+h*M^2*beta)*sinh(h*M))- (alpha*(M^2*(F+h)*(-1+2*h^2*M^2+ cosh(2*h*M)-2*h*M*sinh(2*h*M)))/(8*(h*M*cosh(h*M)+(-1+h*M^2*beta)*sinh(h*M))^2));
end
end
```

and called the function by

```
tol = [1e-5 1e-3];
q = quad(@parameterIntegrate, 0, h,tol)
or
q = quad(@parameterIntegrate, 0,1 + phi*cos(2*pi*0.5),tol)
```

its not working its giving me

```
Error using ==> plus
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your error message means is that for some line of code, there are 2 matrices, but the dimensions don't match, so it can't add them. What I suggest you do to solve this is as follows:

1. Figure out exactly which line of code is causing the problem.
2. If the line has large numbers of variables, simplify them some.
3. Remember that if there are any matrixs at all, and you don't want to do matrix multiplication/division, use the `.*`, `./`, and `.^`.

I suspect that if you change your multiplies/divides with step 3, your problem will go away.

Comment: thanks. i tried step 3, I still get the same message. I will try checking each line in code.